# verify folder content

Tags: matlab

I've

```
resDir = C:\temp\source\
                --------\folder1
                --------\folder2
                --------\file.txt
%list the content of resDir
list = ls(resDir);
```

and I want to check that resDir contains folder1 and folder2 and that they are not empty
is there an equivalent of contains(java) or exist function ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use EXIST function to detect if a particular folder exists.

Function DIR returns structure array of all objects in the directory. Empty folder will contain only 2 objects: `.` (current directory) and `..` (root directory).

```
resDir = 'C:\temp\source\';
folder = 'folder1';
folderfull = fullfile(resDir,folder); %# full path to the folder
if exist(folderfull,'dir')
    foldercontent = dir(folderfull);
    if numel(foldercontent) > 2
        %# folder exists and is not empty
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a built-in equivalent of the Java function you refer to, but Matlab provides all the basics you need to write your own without too much difficulty.  Hit the documentation for `isdir`, `fileparts`, etc.

Comment: I would like to check that resDir contains folder named folder1

Comment: And you have all the tools to write a small function that does just that.